# Retorno de poligono

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Tenho localizações de um poligono salvas em um BD. Retorno essas localizações ao JavaScript por um JSON como este:

```
    [{"lat":"-21.9838014173847","lng":"-49.409637451171875"},{"lat":"-20.3034175184893","lng":"-45.410614013671875"},{"lat":"-23.725011735951796","lng":"-44.180145263671875"},{"lat":"-24.966140159912964","lng":"-48.574676513671875"}]
```

Estou gravando esta informação na variável `var newCoods`, de modo que necessito retornar este poligono em tela quando o botão `Visualizar`é clicado. O método de retorno está sendo feito da seguinte maneira:

```
    var returnPolygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
        map: map,
        paths: newCoords,
        strokeColor: '#FFD700',
        strokeWeight: 3,
        fillColor: '#FFD700',
        fillOpacity: 0.10
    });
    returnPolygon.setMap(map);
```

Quando clico no botão para fazer o retorno, me é passado o seguinte erro:

```
   Uncaught mc {message: "not an Array", name: "InvalidValueError", stack: "Error↵    at new mc ..."}
```

Como devo passar os parâmetros para retorno do polígono?

Comment: Procure em seu seu código alguma variável chamada "mc", caso não esteja no seu código, deve ser algum problema na API do Google Maps. Mas para fins de testes, use esse exemplo do [Google Maps API - Simple Polygon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-simple?hl=pt-br) e veja se funciona. Caso ainda dê o erro, analise melhor o restante do seu código.

Comment: @DouglasGarrido colocando as localizações hard code, funciona. Só não funciona quando ele pega a string pronta do BD, mesmo sem os " " entre os elementos do JSON. A variável `mc` não pertence ao meu código, e sim a uma propriedade da API. Já fiz de diversas formas e nada funcionou até agora, mas como disse, se colocadas as localizações hard code, funciona.

Comment: Que estranho. Verifique no momento em que você chama `new google.maps.Polygon`, se a tem valor na variável `newCoords` e qual é o valor. Utilize o _Console_ do navegador.

Comment: Douglas, já realizei esse tipo de teste também, e sim, a váriavél retorna no valor perfeitamente, mas se envio ao JS como array, no erro ele pede um `objeto`, se envio como `objeto` completo, ela me diz que não é um array, por isso a dúvida...